# Python Patterns

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, conditional-statements

I am not getting how to do it, I keep on running into a problem.

The following is the code:

```
rows = int(input())

for i in range(1,rows):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(" ", end='')

    for j in range(i, rows+1):
        print(j, end='')
    print()

for i in range(rows,0,-1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(" ", end='')

    for i in range(i, rows+1):
        print(j,end='')
        j = j+1   
    print()
```

```
**My Output**
 12345
  2345
   345
    45
     5
    45
   345
  2345
 12345
```

```
**Expected Output**
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
   45
  345
 2345
12345
```

The space in the first column.

How to remove it ????

here,  rows = 6 (as input from the user)

Comment: How about you shorten your space-printing loops by one iteration?

Comment: I did and then it messed up more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is somewhat cleaner:

```
lst = [str(i) for i in range(1, rows+1)]
for i in range(rows):
    print((" "*i) + "".join(lst[i:]) )

for i in range(rows-2, -1, -1):
    print((" "*i) + "".join(lst[i:]) )
```

which results in:

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
   45
  345
 2345
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

> ```
> for i in range(1,rows):
>     for j in range(1,i+1):  # prints at least one spacce
>         print(" ", end='')
> ```

given any positive row number (f.e. `rows=6`) always starts with printing at least one space.

You also mangled the lower number printing loop and printed `j` while counting `i`.

Fix:

```
rows = int(input())

for i in range(1,rows+1):
    for j in range(1,i):      # fix here
        print(" ", end='')

    for k in range(i, rows+1):
        print(k, end='')
    print()

for i in range(rows-1,0,-1):
    for j in range(1,i):      # fix here 
        print(" ", end='')

    for i in range(i, rows+1):   # some fixing here,
        print(i,end='')          # you mangled i/j
    print()
```

---

For this kind of formatting the [string format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) can be used:

```
rows = int(input())   # 5
tobeprinted=''.join(map(str,range(1,rows+1)))

for n in range(rows):
    print(f"{tobeprinted[n:]:>{rows}}")   # right align formatting
for n in range(rows-2 ,-1,-1):
    print(f"{tobeprinted[n:]:>{rows}}")   # right align formatting
```

Output:

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
   45
  345
 2345
12345
```

Answer (score -1):

Made some changes to code (range start from 2). It works now. However, I believe your code is not the optimal way to approach this.

```py
    rows = int(input())

    for i in range(1,rows):
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            print(" ", end='')
    for j in range(i, rows+1):
        print(j, end='')
    print()

    for i in range(rows,0,-1):
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            print(" ", end='')
    for j in range(i, rows+1):
        print(j,end='')
        j = j+1   
    print()
```